# Julia many allocations using Distributed and SharedArrays with @sync/@async

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I am trying to understand how to use the package Distributed together with SharedArrays to perform parallel operations with julia. Just as an example I am takingt a simple Montecarlo average method

```
using Distributed 
using SharedArrays
using Statistics

const NWorkers = 2
const Ns = Int(1e6)


function parallelRun()

    addprocs(NWorkers)
    procsID = workers()

    A = SharedArray{Float64,1}(Ns)
    println("starting loop")

    for i=1:2:Ns
        #parallel block
        @sync for p=1:NWorkers
                @async A[i+p-1] = remotecall_fetch(rand,procsID[p]);
        end
    end

    println(mean(A))
end


function singleRun()
    A = zeros(Ns)
    for i=1:Ns
        A[i] = rand()
    end
 
    println(mean(A))
end
```

However if I @time both functions I get

```
julia> @time singleRun()
0.49965531193003165
  0.009762 seconds (17 allocations: 7.630 MiB)
julia> @time parallelRun()
0.4994892300029917
 46.319737 seconds (66.99 M allocations: 2.665 GiB, 1.01% gc time)
```

In particular there are many more allocations in the parallel version, which makes the code much slower.

Am I missing something?

By the way the reason why I am using @sync and @async (even if not needed in this framework since every sample can be computed in random order) is just because I would like to apply the same strategy to solve a parabolic PDE numerically with something on the line  of

```
    for t=1:time_steps

        #parallel block
        @sync for p=1:NWorkers
                @async remotecall(make_step_PDE,procsID[p],p);
        end
    end
```

where each worker indexed by p should work on a disjoint set of indices of my equation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the following problems in your code:

- You are spawning a remote task for each value of `i` a and this is just expensive and in the end it takes long. Basically the rule of thumb is to use `@distributed` macro for your load balancing across workers this will just evenly share the work.
- Never put `addprocs` inside your work function because every time you run it, every time you add new processes - spawning a new Julia process also takes lots of time and this was included in your measurements. In practice this means you want to run `addprocs` at some part of the script that performs the initialization or perhaps the processes are added via starting the `julia` process with `-p` or  `--machine-file` parameter
- Finally, always run `@time` always twice - in the first measurement `@time` is also measuring compilation times and the compilation in a distributed environment takes much longer than in a single process.

Your function should look more or less like this

```
using Distributed, SharedArrays
addprocs(4)
@everywhere using Distributed, SharedArrays
function parallelRun(Ns)
    A = SharedArray{Float64,1}(Ns)
    @sync @distributed for i=1:Ns
         A[i] = rand();
    end
    println(mean(A))
end
```

You might also consider completely splitting the data between workers. This in some scenarios is less bug prone and allows you to distribute over many nodes:

```
using Distributed, DistributedArrays
addprocs(4)
@everywhere using Distributed, DistributedArrays
function parallelRun2(Ns)
    d = dzeros(Ns) #creates an array distributed evenly on all workers
    @sync @distributed for i in 1:Ns
        p = localpart(d)
        p[((i-1) % Int(Ns/nworkers())+1] = rand()
    end
    println(mean(d))
end
```